# Junit project running via runas Junit test but not via mvn test command

Tags: maven, junit, plugins

I have created a plugin project for which i have created a plugintest project which holds the junit of plugin project used plugin project as dependency in the pluginTest project . When i run the pluginTest project via IDE i.e rc->runas->junit test it runs fine but when i run as mvn test via command or via IDE i get the below error

```
 [[1;31mERROR[m] com.advantest.kohai.test.utils.MetricsTest.test7WriteCsv  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.advantest.kohai.utils.Logger
```

below is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kohaiTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>kohaiTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Kohai Test</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse-p2</id>
            <url>https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/com/advantest/kohai</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Add the Surefire Plugin configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- Add any necessary configurations -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

    <properties>
        <osgi.platform>linux</osgi.platform>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.205.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.04</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.aarch64</artifactId>
            <version>3.124.200</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.advantest.kohai</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.advantest.kohai.plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

it complains only the logger class but runas junit doesn't . Let me know what is the difference between run as junit test and run maven test and how to fix this.

Comment: "Used plugin project as dependency in the pluginTest project" How? If it is set up in your IDE, maven will not be aware of this dependency. You have 2 choices - either create a multi-module maven project, or move tests to the plugin project. In java world, we typically keep unit tests in same project as the code - so I would out for the latter, unless you have a good reason not to do so. Does that answer your question? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: no i added the plugin project as dependency in my test project hence maven is able recongnise all other classes .